# What's Deno equivalent of Node.js Buffer.from(string)

Tags: node.js, deno

How can I convert a string to a buffer?

I tried: `Uint8Array.from('hello world')` but it isn't working

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The equivalent of `Buffer.from('Hello World')` is:

```
const encoder = new TextEncoder()
const buffer = encoder.encode('Hello World');
```

If you want to decode it back, you'll need to use [`TextDecoder`](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#TextDecoder).

```
const decoder = new TextDecoder()
console.log(decoder.decode(buffer))
```

Deno tries to implement [Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) when possible, reason why it works the same way on the browser.

---

```js
const decoder = new TextDecoder();
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const buffer = encoder.encode('Hello World');

console.log(buffer);
console.log(decoder.decode(buffer))
```

---

Have in mind that Node.js' `Buffer` supports multiple encodings, such as `base64` or `hex`, which won't work with [`TextDecoder`](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#TextDecoder)

So if you have a `base64` string and want to convert it to `utf8` instead of doing:

```
const base64String = Buffer.from('Hello World').toString('base64'); // Hello World
const utf8String = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64').toString();
```

You would need to use [`atob`](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#atob) (Same as [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob)) instead:

```js
const base64String = btoa('Hello World');
const utf8String = atob(base64String);
console.log('Base64:', base64String);
console.log('utf8string:', utf8String);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the last part of using btoa and atob. You are a life saver!

Comment: atob doesn't work with Japanese character set