# What is the Deno equivalent of Node's Buffer.from(string, "binary")?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deno

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61813646/whats-deno-equivalent-of-node-js-buffer-fromstring), but it lacks information about the "binary" encoding. `TextEncoder` is (seemingly) not an equivalent for "binary" in Deno.

Here is an example:

Deno

```js
const str = "ºRFl¶é(÷LõÎW0 Náò8ìÉPPv\0";
const bytes = new TextEncoder().encode(str);
console.log(crypto.createHash("sha256").update(bytes).digest("hex"));
```

Outputs: `65e16c433fdc795b29668dc1d189b79f2b809dc4623b03c0b9c551bd83d67069`

Node

```js
const str = "ºRFl¶é(÷LõÎW0 Náò8ìÉPPv\0";
const buffer = Buffer.from(str, "binary");
console.log(crypto.createHash("sha256").update(buffer).digest("hex"));
```

Node outputs: `fb6d4a2f86e91b13fe2d5a6d2e6ebb9b6f66e18a733b68acbf9ac3c5e56571d0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node's (deprecated) `binary` encoding is actually `latin-1` (ISO-8859-1).

Assuming that your string does not use characters outside that range, you can create a byte array by converting the individual characters to their UTF-16 code unit values:

```
import { createHash } from "https://deno.land/std/hash/mod.ts";

const str = "ºRFl¶é(÷LõÎW0 Náò8ìÉPPv\0";
const bytes = Uint8Array.from([...str].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)));

console.log(createHash("sha256").update(bytes).toString());
```

Which, as required, outputs:

```
fb6d4a2f86e91b13fe2d5a6d2e6ebb9b6f66e18a733b68acbf9ac3c5e56571d0
```